# Send email with custom tokens on event?

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I am trying to make a rule which when acted upon will send an email with custom details based on the rule arguments.

I made my rule event and that's all working fine it shows up, but when I add an action to "`Send mail`" and then look at all of the `Replacement patterns` non of my tokens show up, only site-information tokens show up.

Token Functions

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_token_list()
 */
function mahjong_token_list($type = 'all') {
  if ($type == 'all' || $type == 'mahjong') {
    $tokens['mahjong'] = array(
      'package_name' => t('The name of the package'),
    );
  }

  return $tokens;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook token api
 */
function mahjong_token_values($type, $object = NULL, $options = array()) {
  $tokens = array();
  var_dump($object);
  if ($object) {
    if ($type == 'mahjong') {
      $tokens = array(
        'user_name' => $object->name,
        'user_email' => $object->email,
        'user_score' => $object->score,
      );
    }
  }

  return $tokens;
}
```

Rules Function

```
function mahjong_rules_event_info() {
  return array(
    'mahjong_won' => array(
      'label' => t('A person won the mahjong game.'),
      'module' => 'mahjong',
      'group' => 'Rules',
      'arguments' => array(
        'user' => array('type' => 'mahjong', 'label' => t('The user who won the mahjong game.')),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the data from the rules argument pass to the action to send an email?

Answer (score 1):

If "mahjong" is just an arbitrary object type, you need to declare it to Rules using hook_rules_data_info and specify the "token type" so that Rules knows what to pass to the token API.

But if the "mahjong" object is a Drupal User entity, you shouldn't need to implement hook_token_* at all.

Instead, when you define your Rules event, the argument should be of type "user". Rules will then know what fields are defined on the entity.

Comment: It ended up being a mix of that and me using Drupal 6 functions not 7.